# How to check at runtime whether an asset exist

Tags: flutter

I now that this question was asked multiple times but i want to check if asset exists at runtime without async. Is that even possible?

thanks for answers

Comment: like where should we check?

Comment: my idea was to check if flutter throws an error when i load an asset or not. and my question is how i can to that

Comment: In onInit method

Comment: i dont understand what you mean @OMiShah

Comment: kinda getting you at init method you want to access the file, are you directly accessing the file in file system or trying to load a image to a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting error while accessing a file in the init() method of a stateFulWidget (you should be getting the error), do like this

```
init(){ //this should be non aynchronous and is
 yourAsyncFileAccessMethod();
}

yourAsyncFileAccessMethod() async { //this can be aynchronous
 await //access and process file here
}
```